# matching text with speech to text arabic

Tags: java, arrays, string-matching, speech-to-text, jaro-winkler

I made a speech to text applications Arabic. the result of the speech text will be compared to the existing text in the array. with string algorithms macthing Jaro-Winkler distance
I've been counting the manual of all text input with text that is in the array and the result is 1.0. BUT when the application is run in accordance with the result of the comparison is not calculation.

This text array data:

```
int [] soal={R.raw.alikhlas,R.raw.alfalaq,R.raw.alkafirun};
String [] jawaban={"لم يلدولم يولد","ومن شرغاسق اذاوقب","ولاانتم عبدون مااعبد"};
```

The taking of the array and the input speech to text

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
         String hasil = result.get(0);
                JaroWinkler jw = new JaroWinkler();
            String angka = String.valueOf(jw.similarity(hasil,jawaban[0]));

             txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0) + "\n"+angka);

            }
```

this algorithm Jaro Winkler Distance

```
public final double similarity(final String s1, final String s2) {
    if (s1 == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("s1 must not be null");
    }

    if (s2 == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("s2 must not be null");
    }

    if (s1.equals(s2)) {
        return 1;
    }

    int[] mtp = matches(s1, s2);
    float m = mtp[0];
    if (m == 0) {
        return 0f;
    }
    double j = ((m /  s1.length() + m / s2.length() + (m - mtp[1]) / m))
            / THREE;

    AppLog.logString("Nilai m = " +m);
    AppLog.logString("Nilai s1 = " +s1.length());
    AppLog.logString("Nilai s2 = " +s2.length());
    AppLog.logString("Nilai mtp = " +mtp[1]);
    AppLog.logString("Nilai J = " +j);

    double jw = j;

    if (j > getThreshold()) {
        jw = j + Math.min(JW_COEF, 1.0 / mtp[THREE]) * mtp[2] * (1 - j);

        AppLog.logString("Nilai mtp = " +mtp[THREE]);
        AppLog.logString("Nilai mtp2 = " +mtp[2]);
        AppLog.logString("Nilai Jw = " +jw);
    }
    return jw;
}
public final double distance(final String s1, final String s2) {
    return 1.0 - similarity(s1, s2);
}

private int[] matches(final String s1, final String s2) {
    String max, min;
    if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
        max = s1;
        min = s2;
    } else {
        max = s2;
        min = s1;
    }
    int range = Math.max(max.length() / 2 - 1, 0);

    int[] matchIndexes = new int[min.length()];
    Arrays.fill(matchIndexes, -1);
    boolean[] matchFlags = new boolean[max.length()];
    int matches = 0;
    for (int mi = 0; mi < min.length(); mi++) {
        char c1 = min.charAt(mi); //ntuk mengambil karakter pada sebuah String sesuai index
        for (int xi = Math.max(mi - range, 0),
             xn = Math.min(mi + range + 1, max.length()); xi < xn; xi++) {
            if (!matchFlags[xi] && c1 == max.charAt(xi)) {
                matchIndexes[mi] = xi;
                matchFlags[xi] = true;
                matches++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    char[] ms1 = new char[matches];
    char[] ms2 = new char[matches];
    for (int i = 0, si = 0; i < min.length(); i++) {
        if (matchIndexes[i] != -1) {
            ms1[si] = min.charAt(i);
            si++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0, si = 0; i < max.length(); i++) {
        if (matchFlags[i]) {
            ms2[si] = max.charAt(i);
            si++;
        }
    }
    int transpositions = 0;
    for (int mi = 0; mi < ms1.length; mi++) {
        if (ms1[mi] != ms2[mi]) {
            transpositions++;
        }
    }
    int prefix = 0;
    for (int mi = 0; mi < min.length(); mi++) {
        if (s1.charAt(mi) == s2.charAt(mi)) {
            prefix++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return new int[]{matches, transpositions / 2, prefix, max.length()};
}
```